# Scroll gridview with background

Tags: android-layout, gridview, scrollview

This is my stages layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/loStage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/svStage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:rotation="-90">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/bgstage">

                    <GridView
                        android:id="@+id/gridview"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:numColumns="2"></GridView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

my custom gridview layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:gravity="center"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I created an app (portrait), I used gridview to show my stages, I have 20 stages (10 cols). But I cant use Horizontal Scrollview, so I rotate the scrollview to -90 and rotate children to 90. I use resolution 2:3, so I use layout_weight (Linear Layout). But my ScrollView cant scroll, how can I do it?

Comment: this is my background and stages: http://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2015/11/16/Captured1fb6.jpg